# Change Visual Drag and Drop Clue in RadGrid?

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

when Dragging and Dropping from RadGrid it shows the Columns that are being dragged with the Mouse move, this can be good of drag one or few items but if u drag more then it will look hideous and occupy alot of space that could block u from seeing the Element that you are dopping on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
I have faced this solution in my project and the solution is :

1) attach the GridCreated Event to your RadGrid

```
<ClientSettings AllowRowsDragDrop="True">
       <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" EnableDragToSelectRows="true"></Selecting>
       <ClientEvents OnGridCreated="GridCreated" />
</ClientSettings>
```

2) write The javascript Function to change the Visual trail :

```
function rowDragging(sender, eventArgs) {
           var row = sender._draggedRow;
           row.innerHTML = "<div style='color:green;width:60px;margin-left:10px;'>  Drop on Element</div>";
           row.style.width = 0 + "px";
           row.style.height = 0 + "px";
       }
```

regards